# Anime/cartoon where the main character uses something like monster cars to summon monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime, cartoon

1. The main character's main attire was a blue jacket and black or some other dark coloured pants.
2. Usually battles that happened are 1v1, where each person would put something like a launcher and a vehicle on a table, then they would rip a ripcord out of the vehicle and slam a button which releases the vehicle. The vehicle would go through a portal, then a giant portal would open the monster/creature would come out, then they fight.
3. The setting for the show usually happens at rough terrain looking areas, like massive rocks or near a hill.
4. It aired on Toonami.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, do you recall if the animation 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-animated)?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ECXEwt5LW9Q?t=538?

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[BeyWarriors: Cyborg](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt20770820/)*** (2014–2015)...?

> The show takes place in the abandoned planet of Teslandia, where groups of teenage Beybattlers use the Beyraiderz to summon Cyborg Warriors. Now a war ensues for the Cyborg Warriors to collect tokens and restore Teslandia's beauty.
>
> [image]

- The main character fits your description wears a blue jacket and dark trousers.
- The battles involve each participant pulling a ripcord and then hitting a button a device which sends a miniature vehicle racing along a table toward their opponent's vehicle. Before the vehicles collide, they disappear into little circular portals, and then larger portals appear in the sky, from which emerge giant, cyborg beastmen-like warriors, which do battle with one another.
- In the first episode at least, the battles take place outdoors in a rocky, Arizona-like region.
- According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeyWarriors:_Cyborg), the English-dubbed version of the show aired on Toonami Asia and Toonami India.

> An English dubbed version started airing on Toonami Asia and Toonami India on October 3, 2015.

You can view one of the battles taking place at around the 4:55 mark in the video below.

Comment: The ripcord thing had to be a Beyblade franchise thingamajig